# Using the `find` method of `QueryList` inside HTML template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a way to use methods on `QueryList` inside the HTML template ?

For instance, in the TS file I can have :

```
@ContentChildren(DonneeEntiteDirective) content!: QueryList<DonneeEntiteDirective>
let test = this.content.find(e => e.name === 'surface');
```

But for some reason the same thing inside the HTML template doesn't work :

```html
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content.find(e => e.name === 'surface')"></ng-container>
```

The only way I managed to kind of do it is by doing this :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let template of content">
          <ng-container *ngIf="template.name === column" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template.templateRef"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed arrow functions are not allow in templates.

You can `subscribe` to your `QueryList.changes()` and have a property o your component that is the `ContentChild` you are looking for !

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do it dynamically. I don't know how many elements I want because it depends on a parameter. So I can't declare properties for each in my component.